# Pass multiple values to pipe in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I need to create a search form in Angular 6 with pipe and must pass multiple arguments to pipe .

`nameSearch` , `emailSearch` ,`roleSeach` , `accountSearch`

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of data | searchuser: nameSearch" ></tr>
```

and this my pipe :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchuser'
})
export class SearchuserPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(users: IUser[], nameSearch: string): IUser[] {
    if(!users) return [];
    if(!nameSearch) return users;

    nameSearch=nameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return users.filter(item=>
      {
         return item.desplayName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(nameSearch)
      });
  }
```

please guide me how create pipe search with multi argument .

**Edit :**

```
  transform(users: IUser[], nameSearch: string ,eamilSearch:string,roleSearch:string): IUser[] {
if(!users) return [];
if(!nameSearch) return users;
if(!eamilSearch) return users;
if(!roleSearch) return users;

nameSearch=nameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
return users.filter(item=>
  {
      item.desplayName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(nameSearch),
      item.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(eamilSearch),
      item.description.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(roleSearch)          
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you checked : https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add more parameters to the `transform` method that you'll have to implement in the pipe.

Make these parameters as optional so that you could use them as per your convenience.

Something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

export interface IUser {
  displayName: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  role: string;
  account: string;
  description: string;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchUser'
})
export class SearchUserPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(
    users: IUser[],
    nameSearch?: string,
    emailSearch?: string,
    roleSearch?: string,
    accountSearch?: string
  ): IUser[] {

    if (!users) return [];
    if (!nameSearch) return users;
    nameSearch = nameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    users = [...users.filter(user => user.displayName.toLocaleLowerCase() ===  nameSearch)];

    if (!emailSearch) return users;
    emailSearch = emailSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    users = [...users.filter(user => user.email.toLocaleLowerCase() ===  emailSearch)];

    if (!roleSearch) return users;
    roleSearch = roleSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    users = [...users.filter(user => user.role.toLocaleLowerCase() ===  roleSearch)];

    return users;
  }
}
```

Now in your template, you can simply use this `pipe` and pass arguments separated by a color(`:`), something like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="nameSearch">
<input type="text" placeholder="email" [(ngModel)]="emailSearch">
<input type="text" placeholder="role" [(ngModel)]="roleSearch">
<input type="text" placeholder="account" [(ngModel)]="accountSearch">

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of data | searchUser: nameSearch: emailSearch: roleSearch: accountSearch">
      <td>
        {{ user | json }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's also the Component Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {

  nameSearch = '';
  emailSearch = '';
  roleSearch = '';
  accountSearch = '';

  data = [...];
}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-args-to-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: thanks when i using your code it not show me any list

Comment: @kianoush, could you please add some sample data as well to work with?

Comment: when i use one argument, it work , when i use 3 field just `roleSearch` is work . i put the code in edit question

Comment: Yeah the overall idea is to just use the arguments separated by `:`. But in case of static arguments wrap them around quotes. In case of arguments as I have as of now in the Updated answer and StackBlitz, you can use the properties as I've done.

Comment: i using your code but still not work . just `rolesearch` is work

Comment: @kianoush, I've updated my answer with the updated logic. BTW, you're pivoting away from your quesiton. Your initial quesiton was about passing multiple args to a Pipe. But then your quesiton was shifted to fixing your logic. Please consider creating a different question in the future. This would be better for the site. Creates less noise.

Answer (score 9):

It should be same way the you pass the single parameter with comma separation as follows,

```
export class SearchuserPipe implements PipeTransform {  
   transform(users: IUser[], nameSearch:string, emailSearch:string, roleSearch:
   string):IUser[] {
}
```

and in template,

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of data | searchuser: nameSearch : emailSearch : roleSearch" ></tr>
```

Comment: thanks but when i using this code it not work my pipt  :`transform(users: IUser[], nameSearch: string ,eamilSearch:string,roleSearch:string): IUser[] {
    if(!users) return [];
    if(!nameSearch) return users;
    if(!eamilSearch) return users;
    if(!roleSearch) return users;
    nameSearch=nameSearch.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return users.filter(item=>
      {
          item.desplayName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(nameSearch),
          item.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(eamilSearch),
          item.description.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(roleSearch)          
      });`